# VS code is printing weird Character instead of the given text in C language

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Here I am entering my name `Amir` but is printing weird character `É`

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char Name[64];
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%c", &Name);
    printf("%c", Name);
}
```

Source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfcUD.png

Comment: For strings use `%s`

Comment: Don't place a `&` in front of `Name`

Comment: Didn't your compile generate a warning? Like: `warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'`

Answer (score 1):

Few things to fix here.

Firstly, use the correct format specifiers for printing values. `%c` deals with a character. To print a string you need to use `%s`.

If you *must* use `scanf` then following should work well unless user enters 64 or more characters.

```
scanf("%s", Name);
printf("%s", Name);
```

However, it is highly recommended to avoid using `scanf` to get strings as user input. Use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

```
fgets(name, 63, stdin);
printf("%s", name);
```

I recommend you to read the man page for `fgets()`, but in a nutshell, the benefit of using it over `scanf` is that it prevents array overrun (array out of bounds).